# How do I get Google Sheets to keep US$ and GBP formatting to be the same

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets, i have three columns. The first is "budget" the next is "actual" and the third is "variance."

Budget   Actual  Variance

$10      $3      ($7) <==the last column shows up red

on the next sheet I have the same columns but in GBPs.

Budget   Actual  Variance
10      3      -7 <==the last column shows up blue, no parentheses

does anyone know how to get the variance column to show the same formatting? Nothing I try works.

Thanks!

Comment: this belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using google docs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Daniel A. White but pending an answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284292/request-for-further-clarification-of-naming-and-wiki-summaries-re-some-tags-rela) I suggest for the variance column you try, Format, Number, More Formats, Custom number format...:

USD:    `$#,#.00 ;($#,#.00)[red]`
GBP:    `£#,#.00 ;(£#,#.00)[red]`